# Copy formatted cell contents from Excel to Word without clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I would like to know if it is possible to transfer the contents of a formatted Excel cell to Word without the use of the clip board.

Using a macro to copy and paste works great - but it interferes with the users clipboard, rendering their PC / Workstation a bit useless.

I have done some background research into a property called WordOpenXML

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.wordopenxml%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

My thought process would be to spawn an Excel copy and open the spreadsheet access the inner xml of the Excel cell (or the Open XML) and just set the Property in Word.

That way I know it has transferred like for like - with no use of the clipboard.

Maybe there is another approach - I wondered about spawning a separate clipboard object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to store what's inside the clipboard in a variable at the beginning of the macro. At the end after your copy/paste action you could restore the clipboard to it's original state.